# Use JSON returned page url in a .load jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, return

i have some dynamic pages on my site and trying to use the .load function.

Basically i have a form that has a hidden field that contains the webpage URL.

This is then posted to the php page when the action is processed and then i return this page url in the JSON return.

So

```
$return['pageUrl'] = $pageurl;
```

How do i use this in the:

```
$('.adiv').load("HREF .adiv");
```

I have tried doing like:

```
$('.adiv').load("'+pageUrl+' .adiv");
```

But that is a real stab in the dark and it doesnt work. Any ideas on this?

Comment: I think you might need a little more information to be totally clear as to what you are doing here.

Comment: Where is your page `url` stored in the return result ? Show more relevant code.

Comment: Did the below solution help you out?

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting you correctly and you want to get just the `.adiv` portion of the returned data then you need to have a space between it and the `URL` you are calling as talked about here http://api.jquery.com/load/

If `$pageURL` contains the string value of the `URL` you are trying to load then I would suggest trying this below, notice the concatenation of the parameter with additional space.

```
$(selector).load($pageURL + ' .adiv');
```

Also it should be noted that if a selector is not matched with an element the `load` call will not be performed.